# Disable Hammer.js swiping on the slider?

Tags: jquery, materialize, hammer.js

I'm creating a slider with Materialize CSS's code but on tablet and mobile you can swipe left or right to go to the next slide. I would like to disable this.

I tried googling and checking their documentation page but sadly I could not find anything useful.

The slider page can be found here:

http://materializecss.com/media.html

Answer (score 1):

Found the culprit!

In the materialize.js file on line 3731 there is this line:

```
if (e.gesture.pointerType === "touch") {
```

I removed the *touch* and now the swiping is disabled and the slider is still functional!

Answer (score 0):

i found this in the source code of the website:

```
element.style {
height: 440px;
-touch-action: pan-y;
-webkit-user-drag: none;
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
     }
```

maybe you have to change the touch-action!

Comment: Found the solution! In the materialize.js file I found this on line 3731: `if (e.gesture.pointerType === "touch") {` I removed the **touch** and now it doesn't respond to a finger anymore and the slider is still functional!